# Fill colours and labels not mapping correctly in Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, polygon, spatial, r-sp

I'm using leaflet (for the first time) to create an interactive version of the outputs of some research. I am having an issue that the fill colours and labels are not mapping to the shapefiles correctly.

I'm sure the error is down to me somewhere but after two nights I can't fathom where. Below is an example using a simplified dataset. I've uploaded the data https://gofile.io/?c=DKvFwr

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, data.table, leaflet, sp, maps, leaflet.extras, htmltools, rgdal)


# Load data
data = readRDS("exampleData.RDS")
data %>% str


# Create spatial polygons dataframe
spPolys = data %>%
  group_by(station) %>%
  do(poly=select(., long, lat) %>% Polygon()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(polys=Polygons(list(.$poly),.$station)) %>%
  {SpatialPolygons(.$polys)}

att = data %>% group_by(station) %>% slice(1) %>% select(station, adminRegion, nestedLevel, river, location, area_km2, type) %>% as.data.frame
rownames(att) <- data$station %>% unique

spDF = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spPolys, data = att)
spDF@data


# Mapping
n = length(unique(spDF$adminRegion))
factorPal <- colorFactor(viridis::viridis(n), spDF$adminRegion)

spDF %>%
  leaflet() %>%

  addProviderTiles(provider = providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>%

  addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, 
              fillOpacity = 1.0, fillColor = ~factorPal(adminRegion), 
              label = ~adminRegion) %>%

  addLegend(pal = factorPal, values = ~adminRegion, 
            opacity = 1.0, title = NULL,
            position = "bottomright")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Incorrect labelling** :
I think your line `rownames(att) <- data$station %>% unique` is incorrect (if you have a look at `att`, you can see that the rownames are different from the `station` values).
In my opinion, it should be : `rownames(att) <- att$station`.

**Colours** :
when using `colorFactor()`, it considers all the levels of your variable. If you look at the levels of `spDF$adminRegion`, you can see that all the original 14 levels of `data$adminRegion` are still present.
You have two solutions :

- drop unused levels, and build the palette using the `domain` argument (as you did) :
  `spDF$adminRegion <- fct_drop(spDF$adminRegion)
  factorPal <- colorFactor(viridis::viridis(n), domain = spDF$adminRegion)`
- build the palette using the `levels` argument, keeping only used levels :
  `factorPal <- colorFactor(viridis::viridis(n), levels = unique(spDF$adminRegion))`

The 1st solution gives you the exact same colors as `ggplot2`.

Comment: well that was annoyingly simple! thank you for sifting through it as I was not going to spot either of those issues as I'm not familiar enough with leaflet